# $H_2O$ dissociation by ionization in a discharge tube

Tags: physical-chemistry, plasma-physics, electrochemistry, ionization-energy

As a casual amateur scientist, I wonder if it is efficient to electrolyse water in a discharge tube. I imagine that there would be 4 electrodes arranged perpendicularly. the first set of electrodes would be relatively close one to another.  One would be syringe shaped (hollow tube) that would inject dry steam into the discharge tube in near vacuum, the opposite electrode would be a simple plate. this set of electrodes would be excited by rf. at microwave frequencies.
the second set of electrodes arranged perpendicularly at the tube extremities would be subjected to high voltage DC. to separate the protons and free oxygen and collect them by pumping.

I wonder if the theory is sound.

While electrons would be collected at the cathode, what would happen with oxygen and protons when they hit the electrodes near the collection pump?
Does it mean least reactive electrodes are required? (palladium,platinum)?

What is the energy required for dissociation of water in eV?
Would using a microwave voltage help? 
and what frequency would maximize the efficiency?
Does heat at injection help (dry steam)?
Would NaCl or KOH added to water improve the process?

Comment: This process will still require enough input energy to "unburn" the water into hydrogen and oxygen.  In addition, the hydrogen and oxygen will be mixed when you split the water, which is DANGEROUS.  Note that electrolysis has the advantage of separating the hydrogen and oxygen due to the process design.  Be careful and take precautions against small explosions.

Comment: sure. the energy required would be the same. I read that the alkaline electrolysis process mainly depend on temperature in the cell and voltage. In my setup the variables are input water temp (and subsequent temp drop due to expansion) input water flow, pressure in the chamber with inlet and exhaust setup as to maintain constant pressure, rf voltage, dc voltage, and distance between electrodes and the resultant electric field strength. that is a lot to model before asking for a tube at a tubecrafter...  there are other design variables (electrode material,shape, inlet syringe electrode diam).

Comment: and maybe a pulsed dc and rf with reciprocal duty cycles could help maintain the plasma longer in place for dissociation.

Comment: and of course another set of transverse electrodes to separate oxygen ions and protons. since their mass is different the deflection is not the same if I remember well.